# Div exact height as window height

Tags: jquery, html, css

The div must have the exact height as the screenheight of the visitor (100%) using jquery.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.bg').height(height);
});
```

A very simple code, but isn't working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7b2y/

I have also tried (same result):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.bg').css('height', height);
});
```

Comment: your fiddle didnt include the jquery library, http://jsfiddle.net/k7b2y/1/

Answer (score 4):

it is giving it 100% of window height, but your html, body also have default margins/paddings by the browser itself you have to reset them to have none

```
html,body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7b2y/2/)

If however you are wanting for it to always have the height when like window resizes etc you need to also set the html/body to have 100% height, and the div to have 100% height as well

```
html,body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
    height:100%;
}
.bg {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100px;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7b2y/5/)

Comment: But why isn't it showing a div? The div still doesn't got a height.

Comment: the fiddles i have provided show the grey div, if you are looking at the fiddle you provided you did not include the jquery library which causes your javascript part to fail and not setting a height.

Comment: If you include the jquery library there is still no div? Are you seeing the div?

Comment: For IE, use jQuery 1.9.1 see that Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/k7b2y/13/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/k7b2y/6/

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I dont see the div. Is it possible that my browser settings are wrong? Are you seeing the div?

Comment: Yes i can see the Div. Try different browser

Comment: It works on Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer... I want it to be visible at all browsers, why isn't it working on IE?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {padding:0px;margin:0px;}
.bg {width: 100%;height:100%;}
```